# What are some Applications of Hermitian Positive Definite matrices?

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, applications

I am learning about [Hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix) [positive definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix) matrices and the way that they can be decomposed with [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition). I have learned that these matrices deserve special attention for how often they are used when dealing with numerical linear algebra.

My question is simply: what (real-world) applications are there that use Hermitian positive definite matrices? For example, in statistics the covariance matrix of a multi-variate probability distribution is positive semi-definite. I am also inclined to think that positive definite matrices occur in finite-difference methods of solving PDEs. What other applications of such matrices are there? All thoughts are welcome and examples/sources are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Pretty much everything comes down to a positive definite or positive semi-definite matrix operations at some point in numerical linear algebra. Check any numerical linear algebra book for detials

Answer (score 1):

If your Hermitian matrix has all real entries (is symmetric) then here are a few applications:

1. If the Hessian of $f$ is PSD (positive semidefinite) then $f$ is convex.
2. The covariance matrix is always PSD since it's formed as $\Sigma=(X-\mu)^T(X-\mu)$.
3. The graph Laplacian matrix is diagonally dominant and thus PSD.
4. Positive semidefiniteness defines a partial order on the set of symmetric matrices (this is the foundation of semidefinite programming).